# Legend option destroys pie chart in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

My Chart.js pie is working fine, but when I add the legend option, it disappears, much to my dismay. Other options like title and animation work pretty well, only the legend options ruins the pie. I have looked at the code thoroughly, but can't figure out what I'm not doing right. Below is my code:

```
if ( $('#broadsheet_piechart_sample').length ) {      
    var ctx = document.getElementById("broadsheet_piechart_sample");
    var data = {
        datasets: [{
            data: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
            backgroundColor: ['#455C73', '#9B59B6', '#BDC3C7', '#26B99A', '#3498DB'],
        }],
        labels: ['Dark Gray', 'Purple', 'Gray', 'Green', 'Blue']
    };

    //options
    var options = {
        title: {
            display: true,
            position: "top",
            text: "Test Pie Chart",
            fontSize: 18,
            fontColor: "#111"
        },
        animation: {
            duration: 0
        },
        legend: {
            display: true,
            position: "bottom",
            labels: {
                fontColor: "#333",
                fontSize: 16
            }
        }
    };

    var broadsheet_piechart_sample = new Chart(ctx, {
        data: data,
        type: 'pie',
        options: options
    });  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are may using an old version which can cause this issue.

Please upgrade to the latest CharJs version (`2.7.3`).

Here is what I did for example : [example](https://jsfiddle.net/0mjp0tsa/218/) Just exactly what you did.